# Fitting curve with restricted relative orientations

Tags: optimization, curve-fitting

I have a 3D curve that I need to best-fit (least deviation/error) using fixed-length lines whose orientation depends on the orientation of the previous line segment.

As a simplification from 3D to 2D, you can think of segment N+1 as having the following possible orientations:

- [Orientation of Segment N] - 10-deg
- [Orientation of Segment N] - 5-deg
- [Orientation of Segment N]
- [Orientation of Segment N] + 5-deg
- [Orientation of Segment N] + 10-deg

Therefore, the orientation of segment N+2 is dependent on N+1 as well as N.

The relative orientation between line segments is restricted to {10,5,0,-5,-10} degrees due to the physical system the optimization is simulating. If Segment N is oriented at 0 degrees, the global orientation of Segment N+1 is {10,5,0,-5,-10} (0 + relative orientation). Instead, if N is oriented at 5 degrees, the global orientation of N+1 is {15,10,0,-5} (5 plus relative orientation). The black/red/purple lines in the sketch show how relative orientations accumulate to effect the global orientation of the line.

Consider a scenario where the best-fit is made up of 3500 line segments and each segment can be in one of up to 26 orientations relative to the segment before it. 26^3500 combinations is too large to evaluate all options. I can approach the problem starting at line segment 0 and best-fitting each subsequent segment resulting in 26*3500 combinations, which can be achieved in a reasonable amount of time (say 10 minutes), but this does not yield the optimal result.

I can also look-ahead Y segments and best fit N+1,N+2...N+Y segments at a time. This is more compute-intensive but is feasible for up to a lookahead of about 4 segments. The issue is that this is also not the optimal fit.

I can demonstrate that by making the fit of segment N non-optimal, I can improve the fit at segment N+500, and reduce the overall error of the system. Note that changing the orientation of Segment N requires recomputing segment N through segment 3500, because they are all dependent on the segment before them.

How can I optimize this fitting scenario where increasing error far away from the peak error can significantly reduce overall error?

I feel like I am missing the correct words to use for research on this topic.

[image: line segment orientations and simplified problem sketch]

Additional sketch showing an example of the relative/physical constraints between line segments. Simplified further to only allow +10 or -10 relative orientation between adjacent segments.

[image: sequential, contiguous trapezoids following a curve]

Comment: The physical system being modeled are the pre-cast tunnel lining rings erected behind tunnel boring machines. The machine is attempting to follow a desired alignment, to the lowest overall error.  The rings are fixed geometry, installed in contact with the previous ring, and can be installed in discrete positions (in this example 26 positions). Examples of these consecutive geometries are shown in some images in this blog (not mine): https://geo-technical.blogspot.com/2014/05/week-18-tunnelling-tbm-course-ground.html

Comment: Cross-posted from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/636670.